# docker-compose scaling returns error 'address already in use'. How can I scale and maintain predictable / fixed IPs?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I'm looking to find a way to scale my containers while still maintaining predictable IPs for each of them.
For example I have the following docker-compose.yaml file with an arbitrary image. It has a fixed IP running on a defined network:

e.g.

```
version: '3'

services:
  my_postgres_db:
    image: postgres:9.6.16-alpine
    networks:
      static-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.128.2

networks:
  static-network:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
```

I run the following commands:

```
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose scale my_postgres_db=4
```

And I get the following errors:

```
Creating and starting root_my_postgres_db_2 ... error
Creating and starting root_my_postgres_db_3 ... error
Creating and starting root_my_postgres_db_4 ... error

ERROR: for root_my_postgres_db_2  Cannot start service my_postgres_db: Address already in use

ERROR: for root_my_postgres_db_3  Cannot start service my_postgres_db: Address already in use

ERROR: for root_my_postgres_db_4  Cannot start service my_postgres_db: Address already in use
```

This is understandable since I'm trying to bring up multiple containers that use the same fixed IP.

However, is there a way to scale-up containers while still knowing the IPs that they'd be running on? I can scale without a fixed IP, but I need to communicate with the container without manually checking what its IP is.

I'm starting to move more towards Kubernetes. I know you can have Deployments which contain multiple 'replicas' of containers, essentially scaling and grouping them into one concept. We can then communicate with the Deployment on one IP/Port using a Service.

I'm wondering if there's a way to do this using only Docker / Docker Compose?

Comment: Have you read through [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation?  Within the same Compose file you can use the service block names like `my_postgres_db` as host names, with no additional configuration.  Delete all of the manual `networks:` configuration and especially the static IP addresses; treat the Docker-private IP addresses as an implementation detail.

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you mean?

Comment: In the [Django and PostgreSQL](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) example in the Docker documentation, for example, there's no mention of any IP addresses even though two containers are involved.

Comment: The two can communicate with each other because they're on the same internal docker network. You don't really know what their IPs are unless you were to manually check. 
What I'm trying to get at is how we can fixed / predict their IPs even when we have multiple of the same image running. This way services outside even the dockerhost will be able to communicate

Comment: You can't use the internal IP addresses from off-host at all.  You need to publish `ports:` and use the host's IP address or DNS name.  (You also can't use the internal IP addresses at all if Docker Toolbox is in use, or from Mac or Windows hosts; you can only use them at all if you're running Docker on native Linux and you're making the call from the same host.)

Comment: Sorry @DavidMaze I'm not sure you quite understand the question here. It's not about whether it's possible to access containers from outside the Dockerhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only way to achieve this only using docker-compose is creating separated services with fixed ip for each in your docker-compose files like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  my_postgres_db_1:
    image: postgres:9.6.16-alpine
    networks:
      static-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.128.2
  my_postgres_db_2:
    image: postgres:9.6.16-alpine
    networks:
      static-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.128.3
  my_postgres_db_3:
    image: postgres:9.6.16-alpine
    networks:
      static-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.128.4

networks:
  static-network:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
```

In **kubernetes** you can use use a best approach like [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) or [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) to do this.

StatefulSet is a great choice to achive what you want because it maintain the container spec:

> Each Pod in a StatefulSet derives its hostname from the name of the StatefulSet and the ordinal of the Pod. The pattern for the constructed hostname is $(statefulset name)-$(ordinal).

So if you create a StatefulSet called 'my_postgres_db' with 3 replicas, your container will have every the same name (`my_postgres_db-1`, `my_postgres_db-2` e `my_postgres_db-3`).

I hope it helps.